# Pass User object to Token::replace

Tags: 8, tokens

I've the following code (sample) that runs on Cron and sends SMS to users.

```
$token = \Drupal::token();
$message = Hey, [current-user:account-name];
$message_value = $token->replace($message);
```

When cron run, Getting the SMS text as '*`Hey Anonymous`*' This works correctly on site when user logins in. but not on cron.

So I tried to pass the user object to replace the token like follows but that doesn't work. Getting same result.

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
$user = User::load($uid);
$message_value = $token->replace($message,['user' => $user]);
```

There are so many nodes created using this token. So I can't edit them all with new/custom token. So Is there any way to replace the user token, without writing a custom token?
The other workaround is to use `str_replace` like follows, but there might exists other user tokens in the same text. so not preferable.

```
  $message_value = str_replace('[current-user:account-name]', $name, $message);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `current-user` token will always take its data from the current user, you can't override it with parameters. See `user_tokens`:

```
if ($type == 'current-user') {
  $account = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()
    ->id());
  $bubbleable_metadata
    ->addCacheContexts([
    'user',
  ]);
  $replacements += $token_service
    ->generate('user', $tokens, array(
    'user' => $account,
  ), $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
}
```

If you need to control the account object used for the token, use `user` instead

```
$message = 'Hey, [user:account-name]';
$message_value = $token->replace($message, ['user' => $account]);
```

Comment: Brilliant! as always, you saved my time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach

```
$user = User::load($uid);
$message_value = $token->replace($message,['user' => $user]);
```

doesn't work because of user.tokens.inc:153 (as of 8.8.11):

```
  if ($type == 'current-user') {
    $account = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheContexts(['user']);
    $replacements += $token_service->generate('user', $tokens, ['user' => $account], $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
  }
```

So, depending on where you call the `$token->replace`, you may try to tweek the `\Drupal::currentUser()->id()` by re-setting it temporary.